# Tilelist, maxrows issue.

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am having an issue using the maxrows property of tilelist.

My code looks like:

```
<mx:TileList borderStyle="none"
                                 backgroundAlpha="0"
                                 id="wallpaper_image_list"
                                 rowHeight="108"
                                 columnWidth="123"
                                 showDataTips="true"
                                 itemRenderer="control_panel.wallpaper_thumbnail_template"
                                 height="100%"
                                 width="100%"
                                 maxRows="1"
                                 verticalScrollPolicy="off"
                                 horizontalScrollPolicy="on"
                                 click="setWallpaper(wallpaper_image_list)">
                    </mx:TileList>
```

Everything is working, even maxColumns is working. 
But i want to set the max number of rows to 1 and then provide a horizontal scrollbar only. 
And this not happening.

Can plz tell me where m i making the mistake?

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question above is resolved

Tilelist need 
direction="vertical"
rowCount="1"

If we intend to show as in one single row.

Take care guys. 
happy coding  :)